# English in Algeria?

Tags: english-language, algeria

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language_in_Algeria#Education) suggests that Algeria is actively embracing English.

But an [unnamed expat living](https://www.expatexchange.com/gdview/346/1/13/Algeria/What-cultural-faux-pas-should-I-try-to-avoid-making-in-Algeria) there warns,
“avoid speaking English or any other foreign language in public.”

Since all of the other anguages I speak are even more rare than English in Algeria, I’d like a resolution to this apparent contradiction.

Comment: Obviously if you don’t speak Arabic you will have to try with other languages. I really don’t think it’s offensive to speak English (though of course YMMV greatly on whether you will be understood), but evidently that will signal you as a foreigner/tourist to take advantage of, but that’s pretty universal, not specific to Algeria.